# Macroscopic Matter Waves

Tags: hard-science

I know that mass and and wavelenght are inversely proportional, but would it be possible for a macroscopic being to experience them like it if were a particle? and how?

Comment: Mass and wavelength of what are inversely proportional?  What has both mass and wavelength?  A particle has mass and I can experience mass (do I ever) but does a particle have wavelength?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the wavelenght of the particle´s matter waves. The more mass it has, the longer its waves are. Just like how the wave hypothesis of matter describes it

Comment: Are you referring to the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function_(physics))? It's going to be a bit difficult giving a [tag:hard-science] based answer unless you ask a [tag:hard-science] based question. Can you [edit] to clarify. Please also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways, welcome to Worldbuilding.

Comment: I'm not a physic meister, so I can't really answer reliably. However, to help people understand and have them answer, could you define the principle names you're confronting your ideas with? This way, even if you switch a word or miss an explanation, we'll have something we can relate to.

Comment: "The more mass it has, the longer its waves are." - shorter waves are

Comment: @Willk: [Matter wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave).

Answer (score 1):

I assume the thing you're thinking of is the [de Broglie wavelength equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave): $$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$$
where $h$ is the [Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant), $m$ is the mass of the object and $v$ is its velocity. This would tally with your comment that mass and wavelength are inversely proportional.

Clearly, when $m$ rises above the mass of a subatomic particle, $\lambda$ is *inevitably* very small. The only way to counteract this is to reduce the velocity term as low as possible, but this isn't just about standing still... you have to consider the individual velocity of every particle of the ensemble, and to reduce that you need to reduce the temperatures to low levels. [C60 fullerenes have been demonstrated to undergo interference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251170703_Wave-particle_duality_of_C60_molecules) even at 1000K, but their wavelength at that temperature is a few picometres.

Even larger ensembles have been found to have measurable de Broglie wavelengths... even as big as [a few thousand atoms](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-019-0663-9#:%7E:text=%20Quantum%20superposition%20of%20molecules%20beyond%2025%20kDa,other%20findings%20of%20this%20study%20are...%20More%20) but they had wavelengths of a few tens of femtometres, smaller than the diameter of the molecules involved. A virus might be reasonably expected to have an atomic weight nearly [4 orders of magnitude higher](https://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?&id=106860&ver=2), so even at a temperature of a single kelvin it won't have a wavelength as long as the C60 molecule.

Clearly, defining how small and cold a "being capable of experiencing" is quite outside the scope of this answer, and probably outside of the scope of a "hard science" answer too, so I won't attempt to do so. Clearly though, if something has to be smaller than a bacterium and colder than a millikelvin, the odds of it being able to meaningfully experience anything are slim.

(alas I can't find any non-paywalled sources for *Quantum
superposition of molecules beyond 25 kDa*, but if anyone were to find a publically available copy they'd care to share a link to, that would be great)